# How do I reuse an existing instance of an object in Google Guice?

Tags: java, guice

I am new to Google Guice. As of now, it seems that every time a new binding is created, a new object is created. If you have two of the same object as a constructor parameter (or field, etc) in two different classes, how do you reuse first instance of the object as the second object's constructor argument? For example:

```java
public interface MyInterfaceA{
    //Method declarations
}
```

```java
public class MyClassA implements MyInterfaceA{
    private MyInterfaceC myField;

    @Inject
    public MyClassA(MyInterfaceC myField){
        this.myField = myField;
    }

    //Methods, etc.
}
```

```java
public interface MyInterfaceB{
    //Method declarations
}
```

```java
public class MyClassB implements MyInterfaceB{
    private MyInterfaceC myField;

    @Inject
    public MyClassB(MyInterfaceC myField){
        this.myField = myField;
    }

    //Methods, etc.
}
```

```java
public interface MyInterfaceC{
    //Method declarations
}
```

```java
public class MyClassC implements MyInterfaceC{

    @Inject
    public MyClassC(){
        //Implementation
    }

    //Methods, etc.
}
```

```java
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule{
    @Override
    protected void configure(){
        bind(MyInterfaceA.class).to(MyClassA.class);
        bind(MyInterfaceB.class).to(MyClassB.class);
        bind(MyInterfaceC.class).to(MyClassC.class);
    }
}
```

In this example, I think that MyClassA's constructor is called via Guice with a new instance of MyClassC, and MyClassB's constructor is also called with a new instance of MyClassC. How would I first call MyClassA's constructor with a new instance of MyClassC, but then MyClassB's constructor with that same instance of MyClassC with Guice?

Comment: make `MyClassC` a `@Singleton`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is already commented by @njzk2, i am just adding code to the following. Here MyClassC will be provided with same object instance every time when injected.

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule{
    @Override
    protected void configure(){
        bind(MyInterfaceA.class).to(MyClassA.class);
        bind(MyInterfaceB.class).to(MyClassB.class);
        bind(MyInterfaceC.class).to(MyClassC.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```